# What is the best way to compare a string to another string?

Tags: c++

If I want to compare a string to another string ,is there any particular reason on why i should or shouldn't use

```
word1 ==word2;
```

versus

```
strcmp(word1,word2);
```

?

EDIT 1 : I made a mistake in my question ,forgot to use '==' instead of '='

Comment: This is c++, you should be using `word1.compare(word2)` vs `strcmp`. And the operator for comparison is `==`

Comment: C++? strcmp isn't C++.

Comment: @dandan78 It can be used in c++.

Comment: Are these `std::string`, or C-style character arrays/pointers? The first only works for `std::string` (although it will compile and give surprising results for C-style strings); the second will only work for C-style strings. It also returns zero if the strings are equal, so the equivalent to an equality comparison is `strcmp(word1, word2) == 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
word1 =word2;
```

You shouldn't use this because it is an assignment, not a comparison. The idiomatic way to compare two `std::strings` for *equality* is

```
bool eq = word1 == word2;
```

If you want to know if one of the strings is less-than the other, then use the [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) method:

```
int cmp = word1.compare(word2); // beware: 0 means equality
```

Answer (score 3):

If you declared your variables as `std::string` you must use:

```
word1 == word2
```

But if you declared them as `char*` you must use:

```
strcmp(word1, word2)
```

Comment: What's `string`? Did you mean `std::string`?

Comment: whats the difference between std::string and string ?

Comment: @Gabson `std` is the namespace where the class `string` is declared. It is not necessary to indicate it explicitly in each use if you put `using namespace std;` before in your CPP source file.

Comment: Ok, I know C# and C but not C++ yet. Didn't notice it was C++. thanks

Comment: But you really shouldn't use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Not inside a .h file as it would apply to every file where it is included, but inside a .cpp file it is not bad. As always: you must know what you are doing.

Comment: You shouldn't use it anywhere, not even in a cpp file (perhaps it is acceptable in a small scope). Every day there are SO questions to do with people who used it in a .cpp and ran into trouble. You are negating the benefits of having a namespace, and that has a cost.

Comment: @DWilches: Indeed, inside a source file it merely lays subtle deathtraps for future maintainers of that file, not for everyone who uses it.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp does more than simply check if both strings are equal. From the cplusplus.com reference I got that it

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings: A zero value indicates that both strings are equal. A value
>   greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not
>   match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than
>   zero indicates the opposite.

That's why it should be more efficient to use `if (str1==str2)`

Comment: If `str1` and `str2` are `char*` then comparing them using `str1==str2` would not yield the same effect as `strcmp`. If you use `==` you are merely comparing the address contained in these pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way in C++ to use and process strings is to use the standard `std::string` one.

This class has comparison operators for your convenience:

```
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string foo = "foo", bar = "bar";
    if (foo == bar) {
        ....
    }
}
```

If you instead go the rough and errorful road of using `char*`, then the following is wrong:

```
const char *foo = "foo", *bar = "bar";

if (foo == bar) {
}
```

This just compares the addresses of the `foo`- and `bar`-strings as the variables are pointers really. As a beginner, both pointers and raw string processing are rather tough, so better start with the standard containers (if which `std::string` is one).

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is the more OOP way of doing strings in c++.  A "string" as in a c string is actually an array of characters.  Using `==` with that will not work as you might think, as it will compare the address of the first character (not the content of the string).  For more info look up pointers.  Here you use `strcmp`.

If you are using `std::string` (characterized by `#include <string>` and the declaration `string myvar;` instead of `char* myvar`) use `==`.